# Pagination for the view page is not working in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to use pagination for my view pages but getting error as : Call to a member function links() on array

Limiting to display records using paginate in controller is fine,but issue is when passing to the view. Controller code is:

```
$referredProcedureBookings = Gateway::procedurebooking()->getReferredProcedureBooking()->paginate(5);
            $new_records = [];
            foreach ($referredProcedureBookings as $referredProcedureBooking) 
            {
                $records['ProcedureId'] = $referredProcedureBooking->id;
                $records['ProcedureName'] = $referredProcedureBooking->procedure_name;
                $new_records[] = $records;    
            }
            return view('procedurebookings',compact('new_records');
```

In my view its like this:

```
@foreach($new_records as $new_recordss)
<td><div class="col-md-2"><h5 class="panel-body">{{ $new_recordss['Name'] }}</h5></div></td>

<td><div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-6"><h5 class="panel-body">{{ $new_recordss['Age'] }}</h5></div></td>
@endforeach 
{{ $new_records->links() }}
```

Error i am getting is :Call to a member function links() on array.

Even if i use :{{ $new_records[links()] }}

Then i get :Call to undefined function links()

how should i use the links method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

links method available on $referredProcedureBookings

`$referredProcedureBookings->links()`

so pass `$referredProcedureBookings` to view first.